# Trigger webpage view from linux command line

Tags: linux, web

I am using a shared file download service which deletes the file if the file's web page has not been visited in 30 days. I need to store my files for longer than 30 days.

I am using a Centos 7 based Linux server.

My idea was to create a cron to run a bash script with a command line for each file.

I have tried using the wget, curl and lynx commands but these do not register as the page being visited.

Any ideas on a command that I can use?

The file sharing service is gofile.io and an example file I have uploaded (on the page that is required to be visited) is https://gofile.io/?c=znRpuJ

**Edit:** After looking into it further there appears to be a javascript function which needs to be activated which I think isn't activated by wget/curl/lynx. Is there any way to activate this javascript from the command line?

Comment: Can you please add more details about what happens when you use curl or wget? Have you tried Using a user agent header in curl?

Comment: When I use curl or wget it fetches the website page but it does not trigger the visited counter. I wouldn't know how to use a user agent header.

Comment: Try using a user agent header in curl, like so 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36' Let me know if that helped.

Comment: I tried using the user agent header but it still did not increase the counter.

Comment: You could try going for a selenium script, but I suspect that it might not work for the same reason that curl failed. I'll try whipping one up.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I think that without knowing what is the algorithm gofile uses for counting visits it might be impossible to suggest a working solution.

Comment: Let me know if it solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Make sure you have Python3.
2. Install geckodriver.
3. pip install selenium for Python3.
4. Run the following script:

`from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://gofile.io/?c=znRpuJ"
driver.quit()`

Good luck.